# AWS Glue error org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I keep getting a error trying to run a glue job (see code below).  Similar issues like are all centered around a type mismatch which I understand but for the life of me I cannot resolve my problem.  
 I can get the original data from the catalog just fine, show it.  For this example I just want a single column so selecting just payeekey.  If I would do a count, orderby, other commands and then tried to show again I would get the error.  The code below I'm even creating a new dataframe and forcing the schema on the single column and still getting the error at the second show.  Any advice on how I can resolve?

````
payee catalog table: 
payeekey int
field2   int
field3   string
etc      string

def get_payees(glueContext):                      
    payees = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database = "my-databasee", table_name = "payee",
        catalog_id="9999999999",
        push_down_predicate = get_predicate("payee"))
    
    payees = payees.toDF()                     
    return payees

p = get_payees(glueContext)
p = p.select("payeekey")     <-- just to narrow to single column
p.printSchema()              
p.show(1) 
schema = StructType([
    StructField("payeekey", IntegerType(), True),
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(p.rdd, schema)
df = df.orderBy("payeekey")  
df.printSchema()
df.show(1) <---- ERROR ```

output:
root
 |-- payeekey: integer (nullable = true)
 
 
 +--------+
|payeekey|
+--------+
|  12345|
+--------+
only showing top 1 row


root
 |-- payeekey: integer (nullable = true)
````

The second show creates the following error:

````
  File "/tmp/Access_Test_Script.py", line 504, in <module>
    df.show(1)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 485, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 31) (172.34.53.205 executor 1): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary
    at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToInt(ParquetDictionary.java:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getInt(OnHeapColumnVector.java:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:507)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:232)```
````